# Grails metodo update, instancia.properties = params

Tags: grails, groovy

### ¿Para qué sirve el método properties?

Ejemplo rápido

```
def update(){
  def albumInstance = Album.get(params.id)
  albumInstance.properties = params
  albumInstance.save(flush:true)

  redirect(action: "show", id: albumInstance.id)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

¿Qué son las `properties`?

Una `property` es la combinación de uno o más campos o variables de una clase en `Groovy` y sus respectivos métodos `getters`(para obtener dicha variable) y `setters`(para asignarle valor a esa variable). Estos `getters`y `setter`no aplican si las variables fueran declaradas como `final`.

Te pongo un ejemplo:

```
class Book {
    int id
    String name                                                              
}
```

En este ejemplo, tanto `id` como `name`son `properties`o propiedades de la clase `Book`.

Ahora, en el código estás modificando `albumInstance`, asignándole todas las propiedades (`properties`) con el valor de `params`.

Puedes extenderte un poco más en el tema [acá (en inglés)](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_fields_and_properties).

Comment: Gracias amigo, leeré tus enlaces.